# Is it idiomatic to make a join entity?

Tags: datomic

When I say join entity I mean whatever the datomic equivalent to a SQL join table is. Say I have a `parent` entity with attribute `name` and I have a `child` entity with attribute `name`. `parent` is a in a many to many relationship with `child` as each parent can have multiple children and each child can have two parents.

If I were using SQL I'd create a join table `family` that includes the foreign keys to `parent` and `child`; however with datomic, I have the option to pick either `parent` or `child` to give a reference attribute to the other with a many cardinality. Is this the favored approach over creating a new entity? What if `family` has attributes that are more associated with the family as a whole than individual parents/children; for example, a family priority number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datomic's flexible schema would allow you to model this either way. If you need to model attributes for the family itself, though, it makes more sense for family to be a reified entity.